# How To Represent a class as Spring XML

Tags: java, spring

I have a sample class Person and the setter methods need to manipulate the string passed as its argument before setting it to the object. How do we represent this same class as XML in Spring?

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name.substring(0, name.length()-1);
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    private int age;
}
```

Comment: You can't write Java classes in XML. Java is perfectly fine to write Java classes. What exactly is your question?

Comment: I think you did not understand my Question. Let me put it in another words. If I need to represent this Person Class as a Spring bean How will it be represented.

Comment: The same way as any other. But anyway, configuring Spring with XML is really old-school. Spring recommends using Java config and annotations for years.

Answer (score 0):

You can add below line with relative changes and add it in the spring bean config file.
`<bean id="referenceName" class="com.stack.overflow.Person">`
 Read [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_definition.htm) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

**Using XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

    <bean id="person" class="com.example.bean.Person">
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**Using Bean config class with annotations:**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;


    @Configuration
    public class BeanWireConfig {
     @Bean 
        public Person person(){
           return new Person();
        }

    }
```

Hope this helps..!